# Extract information from source code by IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I have to extract this abstract content into a Google sheet using IMPORTXML.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution by using xpath with @class and importxml
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for not pasting the `xpath` in the answer?

Comment: question has been asked using an image ... the answer too !

Comment: =importxml(url;"//div[@class='abstract-content selected']") using locale FR